# Creating a http web service in message broker

Tags: message-queue, messagebroker

I need to create a http post request that will put a message in a message queue.So far I am able to do it successfull within the test framework i.e: using the integration node.

**My question is how I will be able to test this from a external browser?**

**Do I need to deploy it in an external server?**

Any links or suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Lemmeguess: your integration server is running a flow that intercepts incoming http requests, formulates a message and then puts that message onto a queue? If that's correct, then what's the format for the http message? How is it translated for MQ? Is there a WSDL or JSON-WSD for the http request? Is it fully RESTful?

Comment: @Gralgrathor I didnt know the answer back then..Was a noob in IIB .I just had to deploy it in the integrationserver and test it via some http request client like postman...

Answer (score 1):

I often use curl for testing webservices deployed to IIB. You can use the "-d" parameter to specify a file containing the POST data and this works well for both HTTP and SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think browsers are meant to call web services directly, try SOAPUI for testing.

Message Broker Applications need to be deployed on a Broker and Execution Group or Integration Node and Integration Server (after V9).

Comment: ..I am using the chrom restclient